# Сброс состояния git репозитория на состояние последнего коммита

Tags: git, репозиторий

Здравсвуйте дорогие мастера кода. Подскажите пожалуйста:
Как полностью сбросить состояние непозитория на последний коммит? что-бы всё, что я сделал с проектом, после последнего коммита - полностью анулировалось (созданные файлы удалились, а удалённые восстановились)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> git reset --hard

Никогда не будет лишним почитать [Документацию](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-reset)

Comment: Нужно еще и созданные удалить, а это `git clean`